# Brick or set ID for part?

Tags: part-identification

Going through 130 lbs. of 5 decades worth of parts and can't ID this one part.  Anyone know what it is or where it's from? It appears to be old light gray but may just be really dirty light bley. It is 2x2x1-1/3 tall. Could be missing it's bottom as it doesn't place on studs. Only number on it is 4.
[image]

Comment: Hi JohonnyB, and welcome to Bricks! There are some [limits on what new users can post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) to try an cut down on spam posts and that sort of thing. Once you've earned 10 reputation these should be removed. Depending on how you're using the site, uploading images is fairly easy through the image button on the markdown editor - you can either paste it from your clipboard or upload from your computer or a URL - the actual markdown can be a little confusing I'll admit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a [Technic Engine Piston Square 2 x 2 - Old](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=1891#T=C).

[image]

Comment: The funny underside is because it's intended to have [this part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3651#T=C) inserted to let you attach an axle as a connecting rod.

Comment: @Henrik - Finally got my accounts merged! Thanks for the help :)